# 200A tig welder enough to weld 8mm thick steel flat bar/stainless steel sheet/tubing

Tags: welding

I would like a tig welder. It has to be able to weld 8mm thick steel flat bar so we can fix the front gate if it breaks.

I also want to be able to do stainless and aluminium  for projects.

It seems my budget can only get me at most a 200A machine.. My budget is £500

so would a 200A machine be enough?

also why do people say tig without argon isn't good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

200 A is plenty of power for that relatively thin material. TIG stands for " tungsten inert gas" , without argon there is no inert gas so it is not TIG ( I don't know what it is). You need TIG for aluminum , although it requires practice. MIG is usually the first choice for steel and stainless . However , for MIG the "inert gas" can be replaced with CO2 or flux core wire.

Answer (score 0):

Run a pass from one side doing 4mm and then do the other side, or build up by doing the root and then two further passes to fill the valley.

Mostly depends on your welding skills - had an arc welder (DC) that would run 6mm rods and a 1/2” weld no problem... but I had a lot of practise with that, making sh1t rakes for tractors from broken truck halfshafts...